# SUMIF Function on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, math

**Background -**
I have a pandas DataFrame, containing data that I would like to do some calculation on. Specifically, I need to iterate through every row of the DataFrame and compute a calculation, which if in Excel, would be `=SUMIF`.

**Calculation (`=SUMIFS([% Ownership],[Entity ID],[@[Entity ID]])`) -**
In this calculation, the integer value from the `Entity ID` column is taken, and for every instance of that `Entity ID` located in the `Entity ID` column throughout the DataFrame, it's corresponding `% Ownership` value is summed and printed in the `Entity ID % Column`.

```
>>> df
    Entity ID    % Ownership    Entity ID %
0   12345        100.00         1.000000
1   45643        49.56          0.495551
2   00000        100.00         2.000000
3   00000        100.00         2.000000
```

In the above example:

1. `12345` only appears once in the DataFrame, therefore its `Entity ID` value is 1.000000.
2. `45643` only appears once in the DataFrame (with a 49.56 value), therefore its `Entity ID` value is 0.495551.
3. `00000` appears twice in the DataFrame (both instance with 1.0 values) therefore its `Entity ID` value is 2.000000.

**Useful info:**

1. You will note that the data formatting in the `% Ownership` and `Entity ID %` columns is different (e.g., 100.00 vs 1.00000), this is how the cells are formatted in my Excel workbook, and I would ideally like to use this formatting and decimal rounding if possible.
2. I would like to understand how to iterate through every row in my DataFrame (it's 4000 rows) and perform such a calculation using a for loop, so to effectively perform this calculation for every row.

Comment: `df['Entity ID %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum).div(100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `groupby` to get the sum and `assign` the result directly into the DataFrame like so :

```py
>>> df.assign(Entity_ID_perc = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].sum() / 100)
    Entity ID   % Ownership Entity_ID_perc
0   12345       100.00      1.0000
1   45643       49.56       0.4956
2   00000       100.00      2.0000
3   00000       100.00      2.0000
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad it's as easy I hoped it would be!